# How do I turn a validation list from a cell into a list with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation, dropdown

I have a sheet that I need to paste data to according to the validation lists in those sheets. In the sheet, there are many columns each with their own data validation list - some are written directly as `"yes;no"` others are references `"='$$VALUES$$'!$IJ$1:$IJ$12"`.

What I need is to find a way to add each item in each list to an array. Using the code below I could find the references above.

```
Debug.Print Cells(2, 6).Validation.Formula1
```

Is there any elegant way to store the output as a list containing each valid input. My only idea so far is to first check which type of output I get, and then if it is the list form of "yes;no" then look for the number of ; and then split it item by item. And in case its the sheet range reference split it by sheet and range and convert that range to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, will do it.  I'd set a range rather than using activecell, and also check validation is present to reduce your errors.

```
Sub get_val_lists()

Dim arrOutput() As Variant

If Left(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1, 1) <> "=" Then
    arrOutput = Split(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1, ",")
Else
    arrOutput = Application.Transpose( _
                Range(Mid(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1, 2)).value)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your input, I ended up reaching my own answer while offline sorry. But thanks a lot for your input

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit pressed for time so I ended up doing an inelegant solution myself. Posting it here in case somebody else runs into the same problem.

```
Sub ValidList()
Dim strFormula As String
Dim intLastSemi As Integer
Dim intCurSemi As Integer
Dim intSemi As Integer
Dim aryList() As Variant
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim blnCont As Boolean

Dim strSheet As String
Dim strRange As String
Dim intSplit As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim e As Variant

Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

'This is just an example, turning it into a fucntion based on row and col later
'so now my test validation list is just in A1
Row = 1
Col = 1

strFormula = Cells(Row, Col).Validation.Formula1
intLen = Len(strFormula)
If InStr(1, strFormula, "=") Then 'Sheet reference
   intSplit = InStr(1, strFormula, "!")
   strSheet = Right(Left(strFormula, intSplit - 1), intLen - intSplit - 3)
   strRange = Right(strFormula, intLen - intSplit)

   Set ws = Worksheets(strSheet)
   Set rng = ws.Range(strRange)

   aryList() = rng

ElseIf Not InStr(1, strFormula, ";") Then 'Hardcoded list
    intSemi = 0
    intLastSemi = 0
    blnCont = True
    While blnCont
        intCurSemi = InStr(intLastSemi + 1, strFormula, ";")
        If intCurSemi <> 0 Then
            intSemi = intSemi + 1
            ReDim Preserve aryList(intSemi)
            aryList(intSemi) = Right(Left(strFormula, intCurSemi - 1), intCurSemi - intLastSemi - 1)
            intLastSemi = intCurSemi
        ElseIf intCurSemi = 0 Then
            intSemi = intSemi + 1
            ReDim Preserve aryList(intSemi)
            aryList(intSemi) = Right((strFormula), intLen - intLastSemi)
            blnCont = False
        End If
    Wend
End If

'For my attempt at passing the array to a function
'For Each e In aryList
'    MsgBox e
'Next
'ReDim ValidList(UBound(aryList))
'ValidList = aryList
```

End Sub